# How to format usb device

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, usb-drive, lsusb, disk-formatting

I have a usb stick that doesn't show up in `Dolphin`, my filemanager. 
If I type `lsusb` in the terminal it shows up.

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
```

`Fdisk` doesn't see it.
 `GParted` (GUI) just runs around the block when the device is plugged in. I waited for 15 minutes for `Gparted`, but it got lost and can't find its way home (does nothing not even finding my SSD). 
I just want to format it, so it is usable again. Does anybody know a way to do this?
I use 
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
on an HP Envy 17ce1000n and tripleboot Kubuntu 20.04, Mint 20.3 and Windows 10.

Comment: Any luck with the other 2 OSes? If you can't format it in Windows then it is probably broken.

Comment: No, I can't format it in Windows. It sees it as a usb storage device though. Diskmanager doesn't see it. And in Mint I cannot do anything either with GParted or Fdisk, Thank you for the quick respons. It is new, so I can bring it back.

Comment: SanDisk website used to have an USB flash drive formatter EXE. If you find it, it could work (in Windows).

Comment: If you can exchange it in the store, why don't you do that. It may be broken. Seems the most simple solution. LOL : 'GParted (GUI) just runs around the block when the device is plugged in. I waited for 15 minutes for Gparted, but it got lost and can't find its way home'.

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is still open I would like to inform you that I went back to the store. They tried it and it didn't work, so they gave me another one. Problem solved. Thank you so much for your time and effort reading and responding to my question. 
BTW I also checked out this link on the Mint forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=225722. The output was a whopping 259 lines. Conclusion was when it was inserted it was recognized. Thuhh! I knew that already.